# QODBC - Email Sent Date

Tags: qodbc

I'm using QODC, Just trying to find if anyone knows where the data is stored for the history of the Estimate "Sent Date" or if there is a way to get this from Quickbooks desktop into SQL.  I have been through the tables and cannot see this as record anywhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, I would suggest using QuickBooks Application and exporting the Estimate records to Excel to see if this information is available in the exported excel file. Export the "Estimate" table using QODBC. You can then use join/lookup on both the Excel file.

QODBC is able to access data from QuickBooks using the QuickBooks SDK, which is an embedded feature of the QuickBooks Desktop Application.
QODBC can only use those fields and commands which are allowed by the QuickBooks SDK.

QuickBooks SDK does not provide us the "Sent Date" field in the table Estimate or EstimateLine. Thus, it is not available in QODBC.

QODBC will, of course, support it when this feature is available through SDK. I would request you to get in touch with Intuit with your request.

QuickBooks Support: https://help.quickbooks.intuit.com/en_US/contact

Intuit Developer Support: https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/topic/0TOG0000000kF9KOAU/quickbooks-desktop

QuickBooks SDK: https://static.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/common/newosr/index.html

QODBC Support: http://support.qodbc.com